# AWS Amplify: Unable to delete object

Tags: typescript, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm currently having issues deleting an object that a user owns even when I open up all of the permissions. I am able to create the objects just fine but attempting to delete the object results in an error saying `"Not Authorized to access deleteJobPost on type Mutation"`.

Here's my model:

```
type JobPost
@model
@auth(
    rules: [
        { allow: public, operations: [read] }
        # { allow: private, operations: [read, create], provider: userPools }
        { allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update, delete] }
    ]
) {
id: ID!
companyName: String!
positionTitle: String! }
```

Here's the code that's doing the delete operation:

```
const deleteJobHandler = useCallback(
    async (job: JobPost) => {
        console.log(await Auth.currentSession());
        try {
            await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteJobPost, { input: { id: job.id }}));
        } catch (ex: any) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    },
    [jobs]
);
```

Relevant backend config:

```
"output": {
    "authConfig": {
      "defaultAuthentication": {
        "authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
        "userPoolConfig": {
          "userPoolId": "<redacted>"
        }
      },
      "additionalAuthenticationProviders": [
        {
          "authenticationType": "API_KEY",
          "apiKeyConfig": {
            "apiKeyExpirationDays": 7,
            "apiKeyExpirationDate": "2022-06-05T16:51:50.439Z",
            "description": "app api key"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I have a valid Cognito session and also see the session token being used as the authorization header within the delete request. I've read many guides that are doing the exact same thing and this should be fairly trivial but i'm not having much success. I have ran `amplify codegen model` after every backend update so I know my mutation/queries are all up to date. Anyone else run into something similar or see what i'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that I've been able to delete a JobPost object from my local DataStore but that never ends up syncing with Dynamo (likely due to this authorization error) so the object never actually gets removed in Dynamo.

Comment: I’m running into the same issue. I can’t delete a model from data store and trying with AppSync directly also fails with the same error.